# Is there a function in dart which is equivalent to int(a,b) from python?

Tags: python, flutter, function, dart

I am converting a python program to flutter app.

In python I am using Crypto module and there are these lines

```
 signature = hashlib.sha224(msg.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
 print("Signature: ",signature)
 M = int(signature, 16)
```

In dart also there's a package named Crypto and its giving the same value of signature. Now I want to convert this signature to M like done in the python program int(signature,16).

Is there a function in dart which is equivalent to int(a,b) from python?

Comment: Try  int.parse(signature, radix: 16); . See it here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2624#issuecomment-108315902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int.parse(hex, radix: 16);
```

Or BigInt if the integer equivalent is greater than 2<sup>62</sup> - 1

```
BigInt.parse(hex,radix:16)
```